# Run command if sum of files in a directory exceeds certain limit (Batch/cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a very simple batch file which xcopys all the txt files in a directory to another location. I'd like to put in a check where if the sum of the filesizes in the directory exceeds say 1mb then the copy would proceed or else exit if not.

Another thing I could do would be to check each file individually but a sum of all the files would be a rough and ready solution that should work.

Any pointers would be great as I'm not sure where to start.

```
    rem @echo off
cd /d "c:\test"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do 
   if %%a GTR 1024 (
     echo %%a is more than enough
   ) else (
    echo %%a is less than 1024
   )



pause
```

Comment: It would be useful if you posted some code ...

Comment: `cd /d "c:\some\dir"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do echo %%a

if %%a GTR 1024 echo output
pause`   For some reason, even if the dir size is larger than 1024 the last echo command doesn't run

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the total size of a folder.

```
@echo off
cd /d "d:\target\folder"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do echo %%a
pause
```

If you open a cmd prompt and type `dir` then you will get a list of the files.
Look at the lower few lines and you will see a line that has "File(s)" in it, and that number is what the code above extracts.

This improves the number comparison by removing commas, but be aware that it will only work up to 2 GB.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\some\dir"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do if %%a GTR 1024 echo output & pause
```

Here is an else clause:

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\some\dir"
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do (
   if %%a GTR 1024 (
     echo %%a is more than enough
   ) else ( 
     echo %%a is less than 1025
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: Cheers, that gives me the dir size assigned to %%a. But the following line doesn't seem to work for me `if %%a GTR 1024 xcopy [source] [destination] /Y /Q /V /W /J`

Comment: Thanks, that's gotten me closer. I'm try to add an ELSE statement where if the dir size isn't greater than the set limit an message will be printed. At the moment I have `for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do if %%a GTR 1024 echo success else echo fail
pause` but when I test this it just echos "success else echo fail"

Comment: I reckon I need to nest the if/else statements but when i run the following i get a syntax error `for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir /-c /-p ^|find "File(s)" ') do (               if %%a GTR 1024               (              echo success              ) else (          echo fail              )           )`

Comment: See my edited answer - but just omit the ( after the `do` and also the ) at the end

Comment: I get a syntax error with that, I've edited the OP with the code I have. With syntax highlighting it seems that the ( after `GTR 1024` is part of that statement and not recognized as a closing bracket . It's the same with the ( after ELSE.

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` in your question above.

Comment: Yes, the added code in your opening question - but I noticed that I had left out an `echo` so recopy the code from my post and try it again.

Comment: You're welcome, but be aware that batch math tops out at 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd some_dir
@for /f "tokens=3 delims=)b " %s in ('dir /s ^| find /i "File("') do @set size=%s
@set /a size=%size:,=%
set curr_dir=%cd%
cd ..
@if %size% GTR [LIMIT] xcopy "%curr_dir%" "[c:\destination]" /y /s /i /c /h
```